# How to create Ripple Drawable which is transparent with stroke in default state

Tags: android, rippledrawable

I want to create a ripple drawable like this. But it has no ripple effect.

```
 <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="#777777">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#666666" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity should extends AppCompatActivity and your activity theme or application theme should extends Theme.AppCompat*